How can one perform meta analysis on multiple studies that report paired t test results (with no control group)?
I would like to conduct a meta analysis on studies that adopt a pre post study design with no control group - i.e. all studies report paired t test results based on one sample (same sample within study, different samples across studies). Is this possible? I do not find much guidance online, except for this one: https://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Meta-Analysis_of_Tests_for_Paired_Means_using_a_Fixed-Effects_Model.pdf
Any tutorial or paper for reference? Many thanks in advance.

I am not clear what the purpose of the meta-analysis might be but I suppose you could always back calculate the standardised mean difference and its standard error  using the $t$, the sample size, and the means (if available). Whether that answers your scientific question I cannot say.

@mdewey thank you so much for your reply! So let me provide more context. Multiple studies were conducted to assess the effectiveness of educational programs for the general public on a certain topic. All studies contain a pre post test that shows whether the audience improved in their knowledge through paired-t-test (no control group). My purpose is to assess the overall effectiveness for all programs and perhaps also subgroup effectiveness depending on the program characteristics. I am not sure if and how meta-analysis can be conducted for this purpose.

That looks like a fairly standard meta-analysis. I suggest you find any introductory text on the topic and then come back with a more specific question.

@mdewey thank you for your response! I will look through materials on this and share back here. Anyone else with an idea on this topic - please feel free to add comments.
